# Proving a set is a manifold with boundary

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Say $M\subseteq\Bbb{R^n}$ is a $n$-dimensional manifold, and $N\subseteq M$ an open subset. Moreover, we assume that $\partial N$ is an $(n-1)$ dimensional manifold. I want to prove that $Cl_M(N)$ is an $n$ dimensional manifold with boundary. So my approach is as follows - I know that we can write $Cl_M(N)=N\cup\partial N$ (disjoint union). It's easy to show that $N$ is an $n$ dimensional manifold. Now I'm not quite sure how to take it from here. Obviously $Cl_M(N)$ has boundary but how do I show that it's an $n$ dimensional manifold with boundary?

Comment: Do you consider topological or smooth manifolds?

Comment: @PaulFrost It didn't mention explicitly

Comment: But the question must have some context. What is the **definition** of a manifold?

Comment: @PaulFrost I believe we consider smooth manifolds